# Why isn't an animation montage I'm creating for TwinBlast from Paragon playing?

Tags: animation, unreal-engine5, unreal

I'm trying to leverage some of the animations that ship with the TwinBlast asset from Paragon. I want to use them as animation montages triggered by the Gameplay Ability System. The montage plays fine in the montage editor, but when I try to invoke the montage in a Blueprint (even the character Blueprint), nothing happens. I've tried adjusting blend in and blend out timing, but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

For the montage to play properly, the slot on the animation sequence must be changed to "DefaultGroup.UpperBody":
[image: The slot name on the animation must be changed to "DefaultGroup.UpperBody"]

This was confirmed by the following videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffuq5k-j0AY&t=1550s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOiYEkLNUto